# Is there a correspondence between counting curves in P^2 blown up at a point and counting curves in P^2?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{P}^2$ blownup at one point 
and $\beta := d L -2E \in H_2(X, \mathbb{Z})$, where $L$ and $E$ 
denote the class of a line and the exceptional divisor respectively. 
Let $\mathcal{L}_{\beta} \longrightarrow X $ be the divisor bundle 
corresponding to the class $\beta$. Let $\chi$ be some specific 
singularity. For instance you can take $\chi$ to be an $A_k$-singularity 
($y^2+x^{k+1}=0$). Let me define two numbers:

$N_1$ is the number of curves in the linear system $H^0(X, \mathcal{L}_{\beta})$ through the right number of generic points 
and having one singularity of type $\chi$.

$N_2$ is the number of degree $d$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ through 
the right number of generic points having a singularity of type 
$\chi$ and having a simple node ($y^2 + x^2 =0$) at a fixed point (the point at which we blowup and get $X$).

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is it always true that $N_1 = N_2$? Assume that 
$d$ is sufficiently large, so that all necessary transversality 
assumptions hold.

$\textbf{Remark:}$ I think naively that there should be some sort of 
a correspondence between the curves counted in $N_1$ and those 
counted in $N_2$. More generally, if $\beta := dL- mE$, then 
this would be equivalent to counting degree $d$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ 
with an $m$-fold point ($y^m + x^m =0$).

But I am not sure if this is always true (i.e. maybe it depends on what 
that singularity is).